# How to set the number of items in an array based on html form input?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I am working on creating a PHP file and one thing that I'd like to do is have an array (Example 1). From what I understand, and Array is like a list, and I want to also input items on the list (Example 2). But the number of items in the array need to be determined by a number, inputted via a HTML form (Example 3).

Example 1:

```
<?php
$a=array("red","green");
array_push($a,"blue","yellow");
print_r($a);
?>

</body>
</html>
</code>
```

Example 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$a=array("red","green");
array_push($a,"$_POST["color3"]","$_POST["color4"]");
print_r($a);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Example 3.

```
<ol>
<form action="finished.php" method="post">
<li><input type="text" name="color3"></li>
<li><input type="text" name="color4"></li>
</form>
</ol>
```

EDIT:
I hope this is all formatted correctly, and you understand the question. 
To reiterate: The first page is blank with just a form; single input box, where you type in any number ( X ). 
The Second page has the same line repeated over and over (depending on the number X from the previous page), it's line is:
`<li><input type="text" name="color Y"></li>`
Y should count from 1 up infinitely until X is reached. 
The Last page prints it all in a list (array?).

For Example: On the first page we enter the number 3. 
On the second page we have 3 boxes for inputting the names of our chosen colors: Red, Blue, Yellow. 
On the last page we are shown a list of our three colors: Red, blue and yellow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The formatting doesn't look good. :|

Comment: Fixed it! Sorry about that.

Comment: Well, formatting is good, I don't quite understand what you really want. :)

Comment: You should update your question with the explanation you just gave me as a comment to my (now deleted and non relevant) answer. Try to break down the flow more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it what you want (after reading more than once). Let me know if I understood correctly. Let's assume you're using 3 different files (as you wrote in your question).

**file1.php** (a simple form with 1 input and 1 submit button):

```
<form action="file2.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="The amount of elements">
    <input type="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
```

**file2.php** (check if `$_POST` and the value is an integer):

```
if (!empty($_POST['amount'])) {
    if (!is_int($_POST['amount'])) {
        exit('Not an integer');
    }
    ?>
    <form action="file3.php" method="post">
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['amount']; $i++) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="colors[]" placeholder="Enter color name"><br>';
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Done">
    </form>
    <?php
} else {
    exit('Only $_POST method is allowed.');
}
```

**file3.php** (get all results and store an array in variable):

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $colors = $_POST['colors'];
    foreach ($colors as $color => $value) {
        echo '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
    }
    exit;
} else {
    exit('Only $_POST method is allowed.');
}
```

We can add some more security (like checking if it's not empty, etc.), but I'm adding just basic things.

Comment: I changed line 3+4 on file 2.php `{
        exit('Not an integer');
    }` by removing this block. And it allows me through by typing in the number, and it creates it fine.

Comment: This is good, we're halfway there, but my fault. I'm not sure why I said array above, I would like page 3 for them to be inputted into a list. 
So the line `<li><input type="text" name="color3"></li>` from my example three I do need. So **page 2** lets us write _3_ colors ^For Example^ now on **page 3** we want _3_ lines of this `<li><input type="text" name="color3"></li>` example. Does that make sense?

Comment: @WilliamBachynsky Then you can write like this: `foreach($colors as $color => $value) { echo '<li>'.$value.'</li>'; }` This will print out the list of all colors.

Comment: @WilliamBachynsky It is defined. You can see in `foreach` itself (for example, `$color` would be an index in this case).

Comment: @WilliamBachynsky Done.

Comment: This gives me a blank page :o

Comment: @WilliamBachynsky Edit: oh, yea, I forgot to assign. Add above `foreach` this: `$colors = $_POST['colors'];`.

Comment: Beautiful. Exactly what I needed. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ol>
<form action="finished.php" method="post">
<li><input type="text" name="data['color3']"></li>
<li><input type="text" name="data['color4']"></li>
</form>
</ol>
```

then in the finished.php

```
 $_POST['data'];

  print_r($_POST);//print out the whole post
  print_r($_POST['data']); //print out only the data array
```